# Lost Data in the final node while create Singly Linked List in Java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

**Hi there. Thank you all for your comments. The problem solved and I also learn something new about editing and formatting. I want to thumb up every comment and close the post but I did not figure out how to do so, so I will do it later.**

//My original problem below
I cannot print out the data in the last node of the singly linked list when I try to code in the main. Just comment the display method and you will see my original code.

I can only print out all the data when I use the display method outside of the main. Please explain to me why the display method works and the other way doesn't.

Below is my code

```
package learnSingleLinkedList;

public class SinglyLinkedList {
    private ListNode head;
    private static class ListNode
    {
        private int data;
        private ListNode next;
        
        ListNode(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
public void display()
    {
        ListNode current = head;
        while(current!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(current.data+" --> ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.print("Null");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SinglyLinkedList sll = new SinglyLinkedList();
        sll.head = new ListNode(10);
        ListNode second = new ListNode(1);
        ListNode third = new ListNode(8);
        ListNode fourth = new ListNode(11);
        
        sll.head.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        third.next = fourth;
        fourth.next = null;
        
        ListNode current = sll.head;
        while(current.next != null)
        {
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
        
        sll.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code in `main` does `while (current.next != null)` while the one in `display` does `while (current != null)`. That's why you don't print the last node in `main`.

Comment: That is already better, but please also post the output as text. Images have various accessibility issues, so it's better to post as text what can be posted as text.

Comment: change `while(current.next != null)` to `while(current != null)` on main method